# VBA issue with operators

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am facin strange problem looks like = is not working as it should be. I got code below:

```
Dim lineText As String

For Each p In WordDoc.Paragraphs

    lineText = p.Range.Text
    If lineText = "" Then GoTo Dalej
    .....
```

even if i do:

```
lineText = ""
If lineText = "" Then GoTo Dalej
```

its not going to `Dalej` but going next. Looks like its not problem with code but with operators i got similar problem with <>. I tried to workaround tht with InStr or StrComp but its doing completly not as it should be like something inside excel has been changed with application itself. Do you have any idea what this could be?

This is full code:

```
Sub Sprawdz_Pola_Korespondencji_Click()


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim RowNr As Integer
Dim EWS As Worksheet

RowNr = 30
Set EWS = Sheets("Arkusz do wypełnienia")


Dim FileName As Variant, wb As Workbook
FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Word File (*.docx),*.docx", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
If FileName = False Then Exit Sub
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = False

Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName)
Dim p As Paragraph

    If lineText = "" Then GoTo Dalej

    If InStr(lineText, PoleExcel) Then

        EWS.Cells(5, X).Interior.ColorIndex = 18

    Else

        EWS.Cells(5, X).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    End If

Dalej:
Next p

Nastepna:


Loop Until EWS.Cells(RowNr, X) = "KONIEC"


'EWS.Activate  'WordDoc.Activate '<============================================================



WordDoc.Close savechanges:=False 'or false
WordApp.Quit
Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub



    Public Function ReplaceSpaces(strInput As String) As String
    ' Replaces spaces in a string of text with underscores
    Dim Result As String
    Result = strInput
    If InStr(strInput, " ") > 0 Then
        Result = Replace(strInput, " ", "_")
    End If
    ReplaceSpaces = Result
    End Function
```

Comment: I highly doubt it's with the operators, how sure are you of `lineText` have an empty value?

Comment: show the code where you have placed the marker "Dalej". Check for spelling mistakes in Dalej.

Comment: why don't you paste more code... why are you using a GOTO???

Comment: like i wrote even if i use

lineText = ""
If lineText = "" Then 
do seomthing
else
end if

its going to else.

Comment: I suspect @TMcKeown is right in his first comment.  Keep in mind that there are a number of characters that might look like vbNullstring.  Put a break on your `If lineText = "" Then GoTo Dalej`  You can test the value of lineText by using `Asc(lineText)` which will return the ASCII value of the first character in lineText.  A nullstring will return an error.

Comment: i did for test:  lineText = CStr(p.Range.Text)
    something = Asc(lineText) and something i see is 13 after that

Comment: that's a Carriage Return (CR).  Some how your data has that, replace the 13 with an empty string.

Comment: `If Trim(Replace(lineText,Chr(13),vbNullString)) = vbNullString Then ...`  But I agree with others, you should avoid using `GoTo` statements for this, an `If/Else` or `Select Case` method seems better.

Comment: i tried also with that If IsEmpty(lineText) Then GoTo Dalej and its not going to Dalej ;/

Comment: i've posted an answer to strip the CR out of your text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To strip out the CR do this:

```
lineText  = replace(lineText, chr(13), "")
```

Comment: looks like this it helpes 
lineText = Replace(lineText, Chr(13), "")
If lineText = "" Then GoTo Dalej

it went to Dalej, so to understand correctly even if i saw the variable is "" there can be also break line or CR (Char 13) and my variable anyway will show me there is "" am i correct? So i alsways should make that replacment when checking for empty string fields or there could be other possibilites?

Comment: yes, you have to look into the string array of characters to truly know.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write:

```
Next p
Dalej:
```

instead. (i.e. switch round the `Next p` and `Dalej:`). Currently the label is inside the `for` loop.

**But**, it would be far better to use `Exit For` instead of the `GoTo`. Doing this means you don't need to maintain a label.

`GoTo` statements are notoriously brittle.